# How to make the beginning of directory on the new line from the end of terminal in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, directory

In the first screenshot is VS Code on my PC and the second one is from my laptop.

As you can see, I'm using the same code in both screenshots, but in img1, the terminal output ("3") is on the different line with the file directory unlike the second one which stick right into it.

I don't know how to fix this problem, if anyone know how to change this please give me an instruction

[first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NScOy.png)

[second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrrpw.png)

Comment: Try using the same version of Powershell on your laptop as used by your PC (Notice the terminal prompt is different, suggesting different versions of Powershell).

Comment: add a `newline` to your print statement `std::endl`

Comment: @rioV8 both pic have a same code but different way to display and i'm quite confuse that why the output on 2nd pic is hard to see, if i'm using std:: endl, it's just a temporal solution

Comment: @deric4 can you give me some direction of finding my version of powershell and how to install it ?

Comment: This article may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/vscode/using-vscode?view=powershell-7.2#getting-started

as well as installing the PowerShell extension (if you haven't already)
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell